# Replace all characters, except the first, in every word of a string with lowercase

Tags: r, regex, replace, gsub, tolower

I have a string

```
text <- "This String IS a tESt. TRYING TO fINd a waY to do ThiS."
```

and I would like to use gsub in R to replace all characters in every word that is not the first letter to lowercase. Is this possible?

```
desired_output <- "This String Is a test. Trying To find a way to do This."
```

Comment: You can use lookbehind, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pretty way to do this.  We can make a single call to `gsub` in Perl mode, taking advantage of the ability to lowercase a capture group.

```
text <- "This String IS a tESt. TRYING TO fINd a waY to do ThiS."
gsub("(?<=\\b.)(.*?)\\b", "\\L\\1", text, perl=TRUE)

[1] "This String Is a test. Trying To find a way to do This."
```

### Demo

Comment: How very pretty, thank you!! I guess i'll take this opportunity to ask if you would happen to know an online resource with comprehensive list of regex syntax in R.

Comment: Any good regex resource will help you with R regex.  Actually, Stack Overflow is a very good resource for this.

Answer (score 0):

There should be some pretty way to do this however, one way is by splitting each word and lowering all the characters of the word except the first one and then `paste` the string back.

```
paste0(sapply(strsplit(text, " ")[[1]], function(x) 
 paste0(substr(x, 1, 1),tolower(substr(x, 2, nchar(x))))), collapse = " ")

#[1] "This String Is a test. Trying To find a way to do This."
```

---

Detailed step by step explanation :

```
strsplit(text, " ")[[1]]

#[1] "This"   "String" "IS"     "a"      "tESt."  "TRYING" "TO"     "fINd"  
# [9] "a"      "waY"    "to"     "do"     "ThiS." 

sapply(strsplit(text, " ")[[1]], function(x) 
         paste0(substr(x, 1, 1),tolower(substr(x, 2, nchar(x)))))

#   This   String       IS        a    tESt.   TRYING       TO     fINd 
#  "This" "String"     "Is"      "a"  "test." "Trying"     "To"   "find" 
#       a      waY       to       do    ThiS. 
#     "a"    "way"     "to"     "do"  "This." 


paste0(sapply(strsplit(text, " ")[[1]], function(x) 
  paste0(substr(x, 1, 1),tolower(substr(x, 2, nchar(x))))), collapse = " ")

#[1] "This String Is a test. Trying To find a way to do This."
```

Comment: I just received a nasty downvote.  I've reversed yours, and would ask that you do the same.